# Global function pointer to a method errors "mismatched types"

Tags: rust

I want to make a global function pointer pointing to a class method, so I did something like the following minimal reproducible example:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    data: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn foo(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.data);
    }
}

type FooFn = fn(&Foo);

const FUNC: FooFn = Foo::foo;

fn main() {
    let data = String::from("hello");
    let foo = Foo { data: &data };
    FUNC(&foo);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=990e8a6269ad7524e144170ebac1b4b4)

But `rustc` gives me this error:

```
$ rustc test.rs
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> test.rs:13:21
   |
13 | const FUNC: FooFn = Foo::foo;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r Foo<'s>)`
              found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r Foo<'_>)`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

What is this error trying to say? How can I fix it?

Comment: Uhm, why is the reason for that, if you already have the access through `Foo::foo`?

Comment: @Netwave my use case is actually I have a global array of function pointers (of type `[FooFn; N]`), unlike the minimal example above I used to reproduce the error. I'd like a way to select the function to call in the global array with an index. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. You might want to extend your [mre] with it, and minimally use just two functions.

Comment: I'm not totally sure why this happens, but a helper free function seems to fix it: `fn foo_foo(f: &Foo<'_>) { f.foo() }` [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e0f1cd9b83b07711446c1191c3c9b4d).

Comment: you can actually use one function but within an one length array. I've been trying to match the lifetimes, but I couldn't. I'm curious how to solve this though.

Comment: @rodrigo, I think is because of the `<'_>` lifetime, I actually got to the weird point on where it complains about them even if they match perfectly. Ill post the playground link in a minute: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6cc06c2ca705a9b7ab18ce7659cfd3e9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function pointers in Rust can have *early-bound* and *late-bound* lifetime parameters. An early-bound lifetime parameter needs to be specified at the time the function pointer is created. A late-bound lifetime parameter is only specified when the function the pointer points to is *called*, and it can be different each time the function is called.

The function pointer type `FooFn` has two late-bound lifetime parameters. As spelled out in the error message, it's definition is equivalent to

```
let FooFn = for<'r, 's> fn(&'r Foo<'s>);
```

The type of `Foo::foo` is different, though. An associated function can only be looked up once the type it is associated with is fully specified. In other words, all lifetime parameters of the self type need to be early-bound. This means `Foo::foo` has one early-bound and one late-bound lifetime parameter. The lifetime parameter of `Foo` gets fixed at the time the function pointer is created, and the function pointer can only be called for that specific lifetime. The compiler denotes this yet-to-be-determined lifetime as `'_` in the error message. (In this context, `'_` would [later be inferred to be `'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#static-lifetime-elision), since it's the only fixed lifetime that makes sense here, but that's not really relevant for this question.)

There are a few ways to work around this. One way is to make `foo()` a free function:

```
fn foo(foo: &Foo) {
    println!("{}", foo.data);
}
```

Another way is to wrap `Foo::foo` in a trivial closure:

```
const FUNC: FooFn = |f| Foo::foo(f);
```

This way, the function we reference is no longer an associated function, and all lifetime parameters can be late-bound.

Comment: This answer makes perfect sense, thanks! A follow-up question on the trivial closure approach: does it cause any overhead at runtime by doing so? Is rustc smart enough to remove the unnecessary closure?

Comment: @eliang While you never get actual _guarantees_ for optimizations to happen, my gut feeling here is that it's a pretty safe bet that the closure will get inlined. If in doubt, you need to look at the generated code, but I'd only bother if you have an actual performance problem